# Unable to copy shell script file from cloud storage to container in GCP

Tags: shell, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, copy, google-cloud-storage

I am Unable to copy shell script file from **cloud storage** to **container** in GCP. I am getting error as shown picture[enter image description here][1]

Code I have used for copy is
**gsutil -m cp gs://test.sh /tmp/test.sh**

Could someone help me on this.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TbnbX.png

Comment: Please don't use images in questions. The text output is easily copied into the question. The image may not outlive the question and it prohibits copy-and-paste for others.

Comment: The error is somewhat clear. The destination folder `/tmp` is not writable by the `gsutil` user account. This is probably intentional|required and you should write the file elsewhere. If you believe the error is incorrect, you can change the folder's permissions using `chmod`. I'll leave you to determine what permissions you would need as such changes should be made thoughtfully.

Comment: It is now possible to use [`gcloud storage cp`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/storage/cp) instead of `gsutil cp`. The `-m` flag is redundant with `gsutil -m cp` for a single file.